# UUIDs for BluetoothMe

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I am trying to convert the project blueToothMe to my own use.  I have changed the UUID in the code

```
NSArray *characteristics = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A1E"], 
                                                         [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A1C"],
                                                         [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A21"], nil];
```

to

```
NSArray *characteristics = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A04"], 
                                                         [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A03"],
                                                         [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A19"], nil];
```

and I can get a connection from the cc2540 but I can't get any of the characteristics services.

I know the battery services UUIDs and want to use them to let the user the battery level.

I have tried to replace:

```
[instance setCharacteristics:characteristics forServiceCBUUID:@"1809"];
[instance setLetWriteDataCBUUID:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"1809"]];

characteristics = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A29"]];

[instance setCharacteristics:characteristics forServiceCBUUID:@"180A"];
```

with

```
[instance setCharacteristics:characteristics forServiceCBUUID:@"2803"];
        [instance setLetWriteDataCBUUID:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"2803"]];

        characteristics = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A19"]];

        [instance setCharacteristics:characteristics forServiceCBUUID:@"180F"];
```

Has anyone worked with this and have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but what is BluetoothMe? Do you have a link to this sample code? What device are you trying to connect to?

Comment: this is the link to blueToothMe: https://github.com/sergiomtzlosa/CoreBluetooth-Demo   I am linking to a bluetoothle module cB−OLP425i−26-A made by connect Blue  it has a texas instrument cc2540 base bluetoothle chip with a battery, and accelerometer.

Comment: Be careful with that code, because he for some reason has placed it under the GPL license. You won't be able to use it in a closed-source product, so you might be best off trying to write your own implementation based on something like Apple's temperature or heart rate monitor code.

Comment: I understand. I'm just trying to understand how this works so I can build my own. I don't understand where to put what UUID codes to connect to specific device and then get correct service. This example seemed to offer an easy way to get it

Comment: Ok what is the best way in  ` - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{  }`  to discover a single service like battery service UUID 180F and the "characteristic battery level UUID 2A19.  Or should I put this in a separate question.

Comment: Got battery  level service and characteristic with this code;        `- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{NSLog(@"peripheral:%@ didDiscoverServices:%@", peripheral, [error localizedDescription]);
    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
        NSLog(@"Service found with UUID: %@", service.UUID);
        if ([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180F"]]) {
            NSLog(@"SAMPLE SERVICE FOUND");
        }
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
    }
   }`

Comment: and this code    `- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{if([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180F"]]) {
        for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {NSLog(@"discovered characteristic %@", characteristic.UUID);
            if([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A19"]]) {
                
                [self.testPeripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];}}}
    NSLog(@"service%@",service);}
now to write level another post